# App doesn't not work when released as valid. Bug?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on an app since a long time ago, i've never been able to released it but I was still coding it. I'm working on flash builder and when debbuging everything is perfect, when exported I only can watch the color of the stage background. As I couldn't use Trace outside of the debugger I converted all my classes as Sprites to check where the issue come from by displaying a textfield.

But I still can't understand. This is okay (in debugger and released) :

```
b = new TextField;       
b.text = "Mytext";      
addChild(b);      
var fetch:Fetch_Tiles = new Fetch_Tiles(arr, "Ground", "Tiles");
```

This is not Okay (of course, in debugger everything works well):

```
var fetch:Fetch_Tiles = new Fetch_Tiles(arr, "Ground", "Tiles");
b = new TextField;    
b.text = "Mytext";    
addChild(b);
```

And, when I say "not Okay" means that my text is not displayed. And the entire following part of my app (so, nothing).

I have to guess that there is a bug coming from that Fetch_Tiles object, bug accepted by the debugger but not when released (???).

But, worse, when trying to display this text in the constructor of my Fetch_Tiles, like this :

```
private var b:TextField;
function Fetch_Tiles($names:Array, $dir:String, $sub:String) {
    b = new TextField;
    b.text = "Mytext";
    addChild(b);
...
```

The same, it works with debugging, not with valid.

Can someone explains me ?...

Comment: Hi Inexo, not sure what's going wrong for you but the only issues I've ever encountered that only come up in a release build but not in a debug build had some kind of timing dependency where when executing at a higher speed caused the errors (assumptions in code based on processing time).  If you have the option I would check out Adobe Scout as it helps with debugging even with release builds since you can get "detailed telemetry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to shaunhusain I discover where the issue does come from, it's not a bug (of course not) but the exception #2148 my browser never show me. I dunno why but my app is not trusted, even in local, to load datas... I could get rid of that exception using this hack -use-network=false putted in the compiler.

http://curtismorley.com/2007/08/31/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-2148/